# Representation of cells in hyperbolic plane

Tags: math, graph-theory

I want to represent the following arrangement of cells (known as an [order-5 square tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-5_square_tiling); image from Wikipedia; *more text below image*):

[image: Order-5 square tiling]

Obviously for a simple grid I can uniquely refer to a given square by its `(x,y)` position relative to the origin, in integer coordinates. To get to adjacent cells, one may simply increment or decrement `x` or `y`. However, on the hyperbolic plane, things get messy, and it's unclear how to refer to a given cell.

**Is there a better visual representation of the order-5 square tiling that would allow intuitive understanding of how to refer to individual cells, and failing that, is there a simple method to give each cell an index** (such as `(x,y)` for the Euclidean plane) **that makes it easy to find its neighbors?**

Answer (score 1):

This question is closely related to a question on Math SE titled [Symbolic coordinates for a hyperbolic grid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85793/35416) Adapting [my answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192407/35416) to the special case of a square (i.e. regular quadrilateral) hyperbolic tiling, I'd suggest the following: Distinguish one square (likely the largest) as the center, and one direction as the starting direction. Then you can describe a path through the tiling as a sequence of move instructions: turn left, turn right, move straight, at the beginning perhaps even turn around. You can abbreviate these to single letters, `l,r,s,t`. So a path is a sequence of such letters, and denotes a unique final square. On the other hand, there are several paths leading to a given square, so this path syntax isn't unique yet. You need to add a normalizing step: from all the possible paths, choose the one which is minimal according to some total order on these words, e.g. shortlex order. You can perhaps automate this normalization using a suitable term rewrite system, completed using the Knuth-Bendix procedure. I can't think of a visual representation which would make much of a difference for any of this.